# Check whether list of items inserted succesfully or not in room table

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

Dao :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertProducts(dataUser: List<Products>)
```

i am inserting list of products in the table at a single time ...i know whether the all data inserted successfully or not

i tried all the ways like return type of Long ( but it is working only for inserting single item )

Also please tell me the viewmodel code ..that how could i receive the success value or failure value..so that i can process the next step easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close. You are inserting multiple items. So it's not going to be `Long` but `List<Long>`(or Array not sure right now if Room can convert it automatically) ([doc](https://androidx.de/androidx/room/EntityInsertionAdapter.html#insertAndReturnId(T))).

Answer (score 1):

> i tried all the ways like return type of Long ( but it is working only for inserting single item ) so

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertProducts(dataUser: List<Products>): LongArray
```

If inserting from a List then the returned value is an LongArray, an element per insert. Each will either be a value greater than 0 (inserted) or -1 not inserted.